# How to use CharacterController and BoxCollider simultaneously?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Here is the problem, I have a troop controlled by `CharacterController` and I want the troop to block if collide with something. So I add a box collider to it. But it's not working, as the figure shows. The cube doesn't block the `BoxCollider` but does block the `CapsuleCollider` in `CharacterController`.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: It just doesn't work.

`Character Controller` is always using its own `CapsuleCollider` and there is nothing you can do about it. It's a feature requested for several years, but there doesn't seem to be any interest to add this feature in the near future.

You need to replace the `CharacterController` with a `Rigidbody` and write your own controller (or copy&paste one) to handle movement. Basically you use [`Rigidbody.AddForce`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) to move your player.

If you need some ideas how to implement it, have a look at these tutorials. They all use a different approach to control movement:
http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-a-ball/moving-the-player
http://unity3d.com/earn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter/moving-the-player
http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/stealth/player-movement

Comment: Actually I add a kinematic rigidbody component to it and make the collider a trigger. Then check the `OnTriggerEnter` to stop the troop.

Answer (score -1):

I'm coming years later, but I encountered the same issue as you, and I managed to solve it by replacing the box collider with a mesh collider, using a cube as the mesh. It's more resource-intensive, but it avoids having to recode everything with a rigidbody.